# Controlling new features in Spring/Apache tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

Is there a good way to manage roll out of new software in Spring/Tomcat configuration. The problem I am trying to address is being able to rollback newly deployed software provided there are no hard dependencies on other moving pieces. For example changed the guts of an algorithm and now want to deploy the new software with the new change off by default and then turning it on on one of the web servers.
An obvious way is to build a session object which has a map of key-value pairs(property,bool) which is populated from a db on a session startup and then the value is persisted for that session. This is so that if the value is reverted back existing sessions which started with the original value retain the original value and giving application consistency.
Is there a more obvious inbuilt mechanism to do this?